# lxc vm access outside the host

Tags: networking, debian, vmware-workstation, bridge, lxc

On Debian 64bit, I configured a lxc like this :

host ip               : 172.16.0.25
vm guest on this host : 172.16.0.44

I've done the bridge on my host

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet manual
        up ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up
        down ifconfig eth0 down

auto br0 
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_fd       0
        address 172.16.0.25
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 172.16.0.52
```

On guest side, I changed the config with

```
lxc.utsname = myGuest
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br0
lxc.network.name = eth0
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:FF:12:34:56:78
lxc.network.ipv4 = 172.16.0.44/24
```

When I run the VM : my host (172.16.0.25) and my guest (172.16.0.44) can ping each other
But now, other physical machines on the same network (172.16.0.0) cannot see my guest.

Same issue from my guest that can only see the IP of its host !

In fact I would like to get the same behaviour than a bridge network on VmWare Workstation. What kind of routage VmWare does to be seen "everywhere" on the network ?

(By the way, my host is already on a ESX server, but I think it is not relevant at this level)

Comment: You should set tcpdump and see what's going on when requests are being made. At this point, I would suspect arp requests not being relayed from host to guests. At least, a layer 2 problem, as there should not be routing issue (same subnet). Is your guest able to ping hosts outside its own host? Is there any firewalling issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your host is virtualized with VMware, then it is plugged to the virtual switch which does not expect any more mac-addresses to be shown than those of VMware virtualized servers (so not lxc inside the VMware guest). So this is definitely a layer 2 issue: VMWare (at least VSwitch) received paquets with a mac-address different than the host mac-address and drop them. So there would be no way for the guest to reach outside its host, as it should go through the Vswitch to do that.

A workaround is to enabled different mac-addresses on the Vswitch. It is performed by editing settings on the Vswitch (on the VMware host, configuration, networking, select the vswitch your lxc-host is connected to, properties, Edit, security, MAC address changes -> Accept).

Comment: Great post Philippe, But The "Accept" flag is already on...

Comment: mmmh thanks! but I don't see any accept flag anywhere, or do I have missed it? ;)

Comment: Ok sorry, the "MAC address changes" of the vswitch0 is already checked with "Accept" value

Comment: Sorry! I may not have told you the appropriate flag to set on; It may be Promiscuous mode (the Vswitch then acts like a dummy network hub - be careful to security issue then, VMware guests would be able to get the traffic of the whole subnet); I am not quite sure about which of these options have to be set up :/ Hope it will help you finding a solution!

Comment: Ok, cool advice. At the end, What you said is if I do all the "stuff" on "physical machine" I will not have the problem  don't you ?

Comment: Exactly; except if your physical machine is itself plugged into a switch which does not accept more than one mac address on its ports (some configurations enforce this for safety reasons)

Comment: You're right !!  Promiscuous mode does it !! (chat ?)

Comment: Glade this is finally working :) cheers!

Comment: This was a pain in my ass as well. I also had to Accept "Forged Transmits" on my dvSwitch configuration.

Comment: For those reding till here. you may want to see this also:
https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/551/network-problem-lxc-same-subnet-as-host-in-vmware